# Lambda Runtime Node 18 and OpenSSL issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, openssl, devops

I've working on a migration from node 16 to node 18 runtime for a few lambdas but I encountered an issue with the certificates. We create a https.Agent() to pass the config to the HTTP request, the pfx property is a buffer of a p12 certificate.

```
const options = {
    pfx: certificate,
    passphrase: 'test',
    rejectUnauthorized: true,
  };

  const sslConfiguredAgent = new https.Agent(options);
```

I found the issue is related to the OpenSSL in the core Node libraries, so to workaround it I tried the next approaches:

- Declare the node variable NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider as a environment variable of the lambda

  - This gives me the error: "Unable to load Legacy Provider" in the Init Fase of the lambda
- Create a wrapper script to set the env variable and then yield the lambda execution

  - This gives FUNCTION_ERROR_INIT_FAILURE when they try to initialize the provisioned concurrency.

Wrapper script accessed from AWS_LAMBDA_EXEC_WRAPPER: /opt/data/wrapper

```
#!/bin/bash

args=("$@")

export NODE_OPTIONS="--openssl-legacy-provider"

exec "${args[@]}"
```

Maybe the error could be related to the script, but I built it based on the information I found about it.

1. Is there a restriction on Node 18 Runtime on lambda to not allow the OpenSSL legacy provider to be used?
2. Do you guys see any enhancement on the wrapper script to make it work?
3. Is there another way to workaround to send the pfx property from the https.Agent() to avoid the Error: unsupported at configSecureContext (node:internal/tls/secure-context:278:15)?

Answer (score 0):

I found my way around this block by updating the cipher on the **pfx** file following this git issue [link](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/40672). Once this was done Node 18 was able to send it through the HTTP Request without using the flag `--openssl-legacy-provider`

Commands used to update the cipher:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in currentFile.p12 -nodes -legacy -out decryptedPfxFile.tmp
openssl pkcs12 -in decryptedPfxFile.tmp -export -out newFile.p12
```

These commands will ask for the passphrase used on the current file.